# SQL query for absentee statement of employees for one year

Tags: mysql

I am deputed as an admin of Railway IPAS for employees biodata and all PAY and Service related job my query is:

I want a SQL query for the total number of employees with zero salary for more than one year in a division or organization (which is absent for more than one year).

Our organization Includes National holidays for 18 days, weekend official leave on Saturday and Sunday (but if an employee is absent continuously for one year then its don't includes the above leaves which is count or treated as absent).

Comment: Your question needs to be detailed. Please explain the table structure to get a clear understanding.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: The Employee Payroll Management System Database consists of 11 tables. It has the Department, Position, Allowances, Deductions, Allowances, Attendance, Employee, Employee Allowances, Employee Deductions, Payroll, Payroll Items/Payslip, and Users Tables.

Comment: kindly help me out for this querry

Comment: can anyone help me out and give me the query of the above said question is help full for me